# How to create an infinite surface in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, space, surface

I want to create an app with many objects on a surface, and you can move through the surface in any direction, also zoom in and out. Like for example Miro or Figma. Is it possible with some libraries and views or I need to use Unity for this? Thanks

I was searching for some solutions but didn't find it